# Laravel - Paginate child records passing parent record ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a parent model called **Integration** and a child model called **IntegrationError**.
In a balde view a list all the **Integration** records and at the end of each, I count child **IntegrationError** records.

When I click on total count child records, I go to another view for listing child records (I pass the integration ID)

`<td><a href="{{ route('administration.integrations.errors', ['id' => $integration->id]) }}">`

In **IntegrationError** controller I search for all the records for the parent ID that I sent:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $integrationserrors = IntegrationError::where('integration_id', $request->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->simplePaginate(15);
        return view('pages.admin.integrations.errors', compact('integrationserrors'));
    }
```

The first set of 15 records are correctly shown in view and the URL formed is (205 is the parenet id): `http://127.0.0.1:8000/administration/integrations/errors?id=205`

But when I click next button, context is lost and the URL formed becomes: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/administration/integrations/errors?page=2`

I don't know if the query done in controller is the problem or how can I maintain context in order to see next set of records while clicking **Next** button.

Anyone can help me?

Regards!

Comment: can you update with your pagination in blade?

Comment: Hi @AlzafanChristian I didn't understand the question, can you please ask again? Regards

Comment: i want to ask, did you use $data->links() for pagination number in blade? just want to see the blade, how you load the page numbers

Comment: OK I understood, this is the code:

```  
<div class="text-center">
 {!! $integrationserrors->links() !!}
</div>
```

Comment: try appending the get request {!! $integrationserrors->appends(['id' => $integration->id])->links() !!}

Comment: thanks @AlzafanChristian still not working that approach.